# Windows Phone 8 Push Service

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification

I'm trying to get Push-Notifications running for one of my windows phone applications.

Basically i copy&pasted the example code of the microsoft msdn page and modified it,
to update my webservice, instead of printing the push-uri to the console.

However, its not working - even with the unmodified example...

Whenever I try to open a push channel, i receive the information, that the push-channel already exists - but its push uri is `null`...

I removed all comments, but added some for information purpose.

Extraction of my Application Constructor:

```
        string channelName = "S0meRandomString.";

        InitializeComponent();

        pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

        if (pushChannel == null)
        {
            pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);
        }

        pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
        pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

        //Without ConnectionStatus check, an Exception is thrown, stating that the channel is already open
        if (pushChannel.ConnectionStatus == ChannelConnectionStatus.Disconnected)
        {
            pushChannel.Open();
        }

        if (pushChannel.ChannelUri != null)
        {
            //this part is basically never executed, because ChannelUri is ALWAYS null.
            //EVEN if ConnectionStatus says Connected...

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            String uriPush = "http://my.domain.tld/app/updatePushChannel.php?device_id=" + Configuration.Instance.GetDeviceID() + "&channel_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uriPush)); //fire and forget for debuging.

            if (!pushChannel.IsShellToastBound)
            {
                pushChannel.BindToShellToast();
            }
        }
```

I read a lot about issues with the push-service server of Microsoft... However, most of the posts are 2-4 years old, and I think "startup issues" with this service should be resolved now?!